# Is my programming logic correct?

Tags: zk

In my programs I use the next logic.

I create a MySession class with methods save, update, delete, loadAllRecordsFromMyTable, findMyRecord, etc, or rather every function that "query" database.
In this class, I put also some static final consts like

```
protected static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("Log");
protected static final List<EntityXYZ> allXYZ = new ArrayList<>();
```

EVERY viewmodal extends class MySession, but not every viewmodal uses all methods in MySession.

Here's my doubts:

- I want to load some static list only once, cause they are immutable data in my database: is it correct to use a static final List<> in MySession? Where I have to load it the first (and unique) time?
- Is this logic the correct one? Otherwise, which is the recommended approach?

Comment: Try Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. However, on that community I could not create the correct ZK tag cause my low reputation, so the question is not really targeted.

Comment: Hum... I don't know how to proceed. Try to tag it as Java and put ZK on the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/102196/is-my-program-logic-correct/?answer=102198#post-id-102198) the answer to many of my doubts.

Thanks to [chillworld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853637/chillworld) for the great advices.